# pyOpenCL increasing times in coping

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencl, pyopencl

I am new with OpenCL, and I've just started with the tutorial. There is one problem with performances: the time it takes to get back results **increases** with the number of executions, although **the copy happens just once**.

```
import numpy as np
import pyopencl as cl
import datetime
import os

def timeelapsed(start):
    return (datetime.datetime.now() - start).total_seconds()
    pass

path = os.getcwd()

# number of executions and problem dimension
ntimes = 100
dim = 1000000

print("DIMENSION %d / REPEATED %d TIMES" % (dim, ntimes))

print("> creating random vectors", end=" ")
time_start = datetime.datetime.now()

a_np = np.random.rand(dim).astype(np.float32)
b_np = np.random.rand(dim).astype(np.float32)

print("took %f seconds" % ( timeelapsed(time_start) ))

print("> creating opencl environment", end=" ")
time_start = datetime.datetime.now()

platform = cl.get_platforms()[0]

# set your device here, on my laptop the GPU is dev[1]
device = platform.get_devices()[1]
    
ctx = cl.Context([device])
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

print("took %f seconds" % ( timeelapsed(time_start) ))

print("> copying vectors to vram", end=" ")
time_start = datetime.datetime.now()

mf = cl.mem_flags
a_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=a_np)
b_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=b_np)

print("took %f seconds" % ( timeelapsed(time_start) ))

print("> building opencl program", end=" ")
time_start = datetime.datetime.now()

prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
__kernel void sum(
    __global const float *a_g, __global const float *b_g, __global float *res_g)
{
  int gid = get_global_id(0);
  res_g[gid] = a_g[gid] + b_g[gid];
}
""").build()

# clprog = open(path + "/opencl/test.cl").read()
# prg = cl.Program(ctx, clprog).build()

print("took %f seconds" % ( timeelapsed(time_start) ))

print("> running opencl program", end=" ")
time_start = datetime.datetime.now()

# first execution
res_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, a_np.nbytes)
prg.sum(queue, a_np.shape, None, a_g, b_g, res_g)

# useless loops
for i in range(ntimes):
  # res_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, a_np.nbytes)
  prg.sum(queue, a_np.shape, None, a_g, b_g, res_g)

print("took %f seconds" % ( timeelapsed(time_start) ))

print("> copying results from vram", end=" ")
time_start = datetime.datetime.now()

res_np = np.empty_like(a_np)
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, res_np, res_g)

print("took %f seconds" % ( timeelapsed(time_start) ))

print("> performing cpu operation", end=" ")
time_start = datetime.datetime.now()

# first execution
q = (a_np + b_np)

# useless loops
for i in range(ntimes):
  q = (a_np + b_np)

print("took %f seconds" % ( timeelapsed(time_start) ))

# Check on CPU with Numpy:
print(res_np - q)
print(np.linalg.norm(res_np - q))
assert np.allclose(res_np, q)
```

Now as far as I can see, I am copying the results **once**, while executing the kernel several times. Now I have executed the program with different repetitions (`ntimes`), so to increase the execution time.

I did expect it to raise, but **not the copy phase**:

```
DIMENSION 1000000 / REPEATED 1000 TIMES
> creating random vectors took 0.020194 seconds
> creating opencl environment took 0.037481 seconds
> copying vectors to vram took 0.000231 seconds
> building opencl program took 0.004193 seconds
> running opencl program took 0.357534 seconds
> copying results from vram took 0.007434 seconds <---------
> performing cpu operation took 0.834830 seconds
[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
0.0


DIMENSION 1000000 / REPEATED 10000 TIMES
> creating random vectors took 0.023443 seconds
> creating opencl environment took 0.035683 seconds
> copying vectors to vram took 0.000184 seconds
> building opencl program took 0.003948 seconds
> running opencl program took 3.223859 seconds
> copying results from vram took 0.070463 seconds <---------
> performing cpu operation took 7.383705 seconds
[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
0.0


DIMENSION 1000000 / REPEATED 100000 TIMES
> creating random vectors took 0.020661 seconds
> creating opencl environment took 0.034528 seconds
> copying vectors to vram took 0.000133 seconds
> building opencl program took 0.003958 seconds
> running opencl program took 34.556174 seconds
> copying results from vram took 0.713254 seconds <---------
> performing cpu operation took 72.453076 seconds
[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
0.0
```

The platform I am developing on is MacBook Pro with the following:

```
<bound method PyCapsule.get_info of <pyopencl.Device 'Intel(R) Iris(TM) Plus Graphics' on 'Apple' at 0x7fe3d05bc8e0>>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The execution profiling was biased, and invalid.

In pyOpenCL, it turns out, you have to call `queue.finish()` in order to avoid miscalculating the call timings, which are **asynchronous**. For instance:

```
print("> copying results from vram", end=" ")
time_start = datetime.datetime.now()

res_np = np.empty_like(a_np)
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, res_np, res_g)

queue.finish() ##### <=== THIS
print("took %f seconds" % ( timeelapsed(time_start) ))
```

The timings now make sense, with execution time increasing linearly with the number of times it is executed, and copying time is "constant":

```
DIMENSION 1000000 / REPEATED 1000 TIMES
> creating random vectors took 0.024582 seconds
> creating opencl environment took 0.036498 seconds
> copying vectors to vram took 0.000192 seconds
> building opencl program took 0.005599 seconds
> running opencl program took 0.321021 seconds <--------------------------------
> copying results from vram took 0.001644 seconds
> performing cpu operation took 0.736778 seconds

DIMENSION 1000000 / REPEATED 10000 TIMES
> creating random vectors took 0.020528 seconds
> creating opencl environment took 0.036981 seconds
> copying vectors to vram took 0.000161 seconds
> building opencl program took 0.003920 seconds
> running opencl program took 3.276146 seconds <--------------------------------
> copying results from vram took 0.002162 seconds
> performing cpu operation took 7.580689 seconds

DIMENSION 1000000 / REPEATED 100000 TIMES
> creating random vectors took 0.019618 seconds
> creating opencl environment took 0.037837 seconds
> copying vectors to vram took 0.000150 seconds
> building opencl program took 0.003931 seconds
> running opencl program took 32.988545 seconds <-------------------------------
> copying results from vram took 0.001898 seconds
> performing cpu operation took 71.370180 seconds
```